# C# database interaction

Tags: c#, database, linq

*What would be the most generic way to handle user-database interaction in `C#`*

I expect being able to easilly swap the database drivers (data providers).

I also think *(not sure if it's possible)* that it would be great if I could switch the data source from something *DB-like* (for example, plain `MySQL` database) to something absolutely another - like data serialized into `xml` or arbitrary binary file. *I suspect the last case would require writing some Query-File interaction wrapper or something like that.*

---

So - could someone **share a way** to achieve the described behavior?

***I can definitely use `LINQ` for my queries and it does introduce some abstraction - but is it enough to make the data sources interchangeable?***

*If yes, then what should I actually do to bring this to life and how would my development pipeline look?*

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small Respository Pattern Walkthrough using the EF Framework:

```
someRepository.Find.Where(something => something.IsRed && something.IsBig)
```

Create a generic interface called 'IRepository' of type  `T` containing all the methods for data access.

It could look like this:

```
interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp);

    T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp);

    // And many more!
}
```

Create an abstract 'Repository' class implementing this interface:

```
class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    TestDataContext _dataContext = TestDataContext(); // Would be your EF Context

    public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        _dataContext.GetTable<T>().Where<T>(exp);
    }

    public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> exp)
    {
        _dataContext.GetTable<T>().Single(exp);
    }

    // And many more!
}
```

We can now create an interface for the `ModelClass` table/objects which implements our 'IRepository' and a concrete class extending the abstract 'Repository' class and implementing the 'IModelClassInterface':

```
interface IModelClassRepository : IRepository<ModelClass>
{
}
```

And the matching repository to implement it:

```
class ModelClassRepository : Repository<ModelClass>, IModelClassRepository
{
}
```

I would suggest using this approach as it gives you a lot of flexibility as well as enough power to control all the tiny entities you have.

Calling those methods will be super easy that way:

```
ModelClassRepository _repo = new ModelClassRepository();
_repo.Find.Where(something => something.IsRed && something.IsBig)
```

Yes, it means that you have to do some work but it is hell easier for you to change the data source later on.

***You can even switch the EF Framework with any dataprovider of your choice. Be it XML, db4o or plain old Txt.***

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the repository pattern.

Asp.net also makes use of what is known as the provider pattern to create swappable components such as the membership provider, sitemap provider, etc.

Comment: Repository pattern should be used in addition to a good database abstraction tool, in my opinion.

Comment: Yeah, use the repository pattern to keep your code from being dependant on any specific database and then use a decent orm such as Entity Framework to save the headache of dealing with sql and change tracking.

Answer (score 0):

1 word.

NHibernate

NH3.0 supports LINQ, and its trival to swap out SQL Server for Posgres or MyFailSQL.

"like data serialized into xml or arbitrary binary file." not sure what this means tho.

Comment: I wouldn't call NHibernate "Generic", but it will support swapping DB's from SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: It's no less not "Generic" than using L2S, EF, LightSpeed, etc. But it address's the ability to use LINQ type queries and swap the DB out.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET framework the de facto standard for this right now is [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx). Take any criticisms you find online of EF with a grain of salt because recently EF version 4 was released which addressed a large number of concerns with the old version - check the dates on articles you read. Right now it is, in my opinion, the best database abstraction tool in the .NET space (that I have tried).

Beware LINQ to SQL, Microsoft is not likely to put many resources into improving the product because EF is now the flagship in this area.

Comment: And if you are new to this then also be aware that LINQ is not the same as LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest that you look into [**LLBLGen Pro**](http://llblgen.com/).  We have been using their ORM and it blows away the competition.  Their new version allows you to use their tool and generate out code for multiple frameworks (entity framework, nhibernate, linq-to-sql).  But their framework seems to be the most flexible for many scenarios.

You can find out more info from Frans on his [**blog**](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/default.aspx). He is the main LLBLGen guru and original creator of LLBLGen.

Comment: Using their Adapter model the entities and database drivers are completely separate which allow for you to point the entities to any supported database driver.

Answer (score 0):

"What would be the most generic way to handle user-database interaction in C#" ?

The most generic way is ADO.NET ... which is just Blocks of SQL or calls to Stored Procedures in your DB, has it's advantages.  However has many disadvantages as it is not easily abstracted to OOP doesn't have any intellisense ... EF is very cool as it addresses many of these shortcomings but if its new to you the syntax takes a little getting used to